# I want to create a website where users will be posting to the site, How would I make each post appear in a separate card?

Tags: python, django

Am creating a website where user will be posting information in the site, but when I post in the site, all post appear in a single card while I want each post to appear in a separate card, How would I do this?? would I have to use Javascript in the front end or python in the back end to accomplish this, and how?

Am using python 3.6.8, and django 2.1.8, I have written a code but all post appear in single materialize card

views

```
def homepage(request):
return render(request=request,
              template_name="main/home.html",
              context={"documents":Documents.objects.all}
```

models

```
class Documents(models.Model):
docs_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
police_station = models.CharField(max_length=200)
docs_details = models.TextField()
docs_pic = models.ImageField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.docs_name
```

Home template

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="">button</a>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m9" >
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            {% for Doc in documents %}
            <p>{{Doc.docs_name}}</p>
            <p>{{Doc.police_station}}</p>
            <p>{{Doc.docs_details}}</p>
            <p>{{Doc.docs_pic}}</p>
            {% endfor %} 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can use either of them depending upon ur choice, whether as server side rendered (i.e using django) or client side(using some sort of javascript). It would be better if you can add your template, home.html to the question above

Comment: thanks for a reply, by now I would like to use python for making it appear separate, please help me the code for  separating

Comment: Yes it is better to use python only because, you are already templating the views from server side. See if the answer below helps

Comment: When you get posted answers  -https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="">button</a>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m9" >
    {% for Doc in documents %}
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
            <p>{{Doc.docs_name}}</p>
            <p>{{Doc.police_station}}</p>
            <p>{{Doc.docs_details}}</p>
            <p>{{Doc.docs_pic}}</p> 
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you desire by simply adding the looping construct outside the  `<div class="card">` like this :

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="">button</a>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s12 m9" >

    {% for Doc in documents %}
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <p>{{Doc.docs_name}}</p>
          <p>{{Doc.police_station}}</p>
          <p>{{Doc.docs_details}}</p>
          <p>{{Doc.docs_pic}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %} 

</div> 
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

This way your card section alone repeats multiple times.
Earlier since the loop was within the card you got all the items within the same card.

Comment: thanks, this one works too, now I understand it was issue of divs